# Got an error on apche localhost configtest

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, localhost

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/private/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
AH00014: Configuration check failed
```

I don't have `apache2` folder in `/private/var/log/` and in `/var/log/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/var/log/apache2 should exist on macOS as it comes with its own Apache server. If it does not you could try to create it yourself again by doing:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2 && sudo chown root:wheel /var/log/apache2
```

Are you trying to get the default macOS Apache up and running or did you try to install one yourself?

You can check to see whether Apache is running with:

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

You can restart (or start in case it isn't running) macOS' Apache with:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```